# Passed argument memory context

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, memory

I came across this while coding:

```
def interpret(command): 
    # comment1: command.replace("()","o").replace("(al)","al") 
    # comment2: print(command)

    res = command.replace("()","o").replace("(al)","al")
    print(res)

interpret("G()(al)")
```

In the above code, I was expecting the string to be replaced at 'comment1' but, I got the same value passed as an argument i.e. "G()(al)" but on storing it in a different location (here, 'res') I was able to get the expected result.

Could you please point out what made Python remember the 'command' original value or is there something like JavaScript's closure or I am unable to see the simple point here?

Comment: `//` is floor division in Python, not a comment. Please [edit] your code to make it valid Python.

Comment: `command.replace` doesn't replace in-place, but returns a new string. Check the documentation!

Comment: Calling `.replace()` on a string does not modify it in-place, it returns the modified version of the string. Just running `command.replace("()","o").replace("(al)","al")` doesn't do anything to the contents of `command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Meaning that a new string is created for the data to be stored in. And since you did not store the result of the replacement operations back into the `command` parameter, the result is never used. Storing the data in another variable `res` also works and might provide more bug-resistance if you want to perform multiple operations on `command` that you might re-arrange later on.